# Magento search can't find products with the word 'and' in the title

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

A client of mine has a product named "**C137-936 and T324-456**"
When Searching for "**C137-936 T324-456**" this product show up in the results, but when explicitly searching for "**C137-936 and T324-456**" the product isn't present.

Why is Magento missing this, and how can this issue be fixed?

Comment: Try to change system configuration for search.
System->configuration->Catalog->Catalog Search->Search Type

Comment: Thanks, Tried it already.  Didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration of the article you must config the visibility for the article to: catalog, search 
or: search

In the search configruation you can change the configuration for the max. searchquery and the max. number of worts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I fail to see how this answers the question. 
The products does appear on search results.

Comment: I thought that the "C137-936 and T324-456" does not appear  becouse the searchquery is to long.

Comment: No, query dues goes through, but product isn't in results.

Comment: I tried it with your articel name with the "and" between. I got the same result. In advanced search it works but not in standard search. In the standard search I got a result with all articles with and in the name.

Comment: So I think it is the searchlogic. If I change the search config to fulltext I got the search result that you want (C137-936 and T324-456).